# Laravel bootstrap after env?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, environment-variables

`bootstrap/app.php` seems to run before my `.env` file is parsed -- all my environment variables are coming out null.

I want to call some method at the start of every request and pass it an environment variable. How can I do that?

Comment: You are too early in the boot process... Take a look at the request lifecycle doc... You have to get in the HTTP kernel... A Middleware perhaps?
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/lifecycle

Comment: Take a look at [Before / After Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#defining-middleware)